# WPF string.format in List(Of String) not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am trying to make a invoice flowdocument by using XAML.

I am using databinding to fill a ItemsControl this works like it should but my text is not aligned. By using:

```
String.Format("{0,-5}x   {1,-25}  €{2}", QT, "Desc", "Price")
```

To write it to a textfile works perfectly but whenever I put it in a List(Of String) it just does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  Dim myCollection As New List(Of String)()

    Dim derpa As String
    derpa = String.Format("{0,-5}x   {1,-25}  €{2}", 4, "PYAH", "123")
    myCollection.Add(derpa)
    derpa = String.Format("{0,-5}x   {1,-25}  €{2}", 44, "PYAH2", "123")
    myCollection.Add(derpa)

    derpa = String.Format("{0,-5}x   {1,-25}  €{2}", 232, "PYAH2we", "33232")
    myCollection.Add(derpa)

    derpa = String.Format("{0,-5}x   {1,-25}  €{2}", 12, "asdasd", "213123")
    myCollection.Add(derpa)

    For Each item In myCollection
        derpaderpa.Text &= vbNewLine & item 'WPF Textblock

    Next
```

Is the current code I have.

Comment: Are you using a container to store each column in the list. ATM each list has a different length so they will not align. Could you put them in a container with a text-align property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text doesn't line up because you are displaying it using a [proportional font, not a fixed width font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion).   With a proportional font, not all characters are the same width - spaces in particular are smaller than letters (and letters vary in size).  The text editor appears aligned because it is using a fixed width font where all the characters are the same size.  If you were to open the text file in MS Word you will see it not line up.

You could change the font in our ItemsControl to a fixed width font (e.g. Lucidia Console).  What you probably want is a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972.aspx) with an embedded GridView which will display each item of information as a separate column - which lines up the data.

Comment: I used a fixed font and this fixed the problem. But is this really the best way to fix it or should I use the second thing you suggested me?

Comment: @Lars - it depends on how you want your application to look.

Comment: Well, eitherway I use listview with embedded Gridview inside of the application but when I print the invoice I use the ItemsControl.